# Duda sobre uso de catch en Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, try-catch

soy nuevo en lo q se refiere a java y me surgio una duda y no encuentro en ningun lado como resolverla.
Estoy haciendo un proyecto para aprender bien como utilizar Netbeans y mysql.
Mi duda es la siguiente:
Estoy usando un catch para mostrar mensajes segun el error. Mi problema es q quiero usar el mismo catch pero q me muestre 2 mensajes distintos, como puedo hacer eso?

```
}catch(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El código postal no existe o no esta cargado","ADVERTENCIA",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
          Ayudaloc abrir = new Ayudaloc();
           abrir.setVisible(true);

}catch(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La provincia no existe o no esta cargada","ADVERTENCIA",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
          Ayudaprov abrir = new Ayudaprov();
           abrir.setVisible(true);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme
Ya q si la provincia o localidad son incorrectas me muestra siempre la tabla de ayuda de localidades y nunca la de provincia

Este es el boton q uso para guardar los datos

```
private void btnguardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    if (txtclnombre.getText().equals("") || txtclapellido.getText().equals("") ||  txtcldireccion.getText().equals("") || txtclcodigopostal.getText().equals("") || txtcltelefono.getText().equals("") || txtclemail.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete todos los campos, faltan datos","ADVERTENCIA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } else {

    try {
        PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO clientes(cl_Nombre,cl_Apellido,cl_direccion,cl_cp,cl_telefono,cl_email,cl_provincia)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pps.setString(1, txtclnombre.getText());
        pps.setString(2, txtclapellido.getText());
        //pps.setString(3, txtcldni.getText());
        pps.setString(3, txtcldireccion.getText());
        pps.setString(4, txtclcodigopostal.getText());
        pps.setString(5, txtcltelefono.getText());
        pps.setString(6, txtclemail.getText());
        pps.setString(7, txtclprovincia.getText());
        pps.executeUpdate();    //ejecutar actualizacion/cambio
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Guardados");
        limpiar();  //limpia los campos
        mostrartabla("");            
    }catch(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El código postal no existe o no esta cargado","ADVERTENCIA",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
          Ayudaloc abrir = new Ayudaloc();
           abrir.setVisible(true);

}catch(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La provincia no existe o no esta cargada","ADVERTENCIA",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
          Ayudaprov abrir = new Ayudaprov();
           abrir.setVisible(true);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PantallaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solo puedes hacer un `catch` para cada tipo de excepción. ¿Puedes mostrar más código para ver lo que quieres? Porque si solo haces un insert habrá que ver si el campo `reason` de la excepción te da la información que buscas...

Comment: ahi agregue el boton para q veas lo q hace.. osea q no puedo usar la misma excepcion para mostrar 2 mensajes distintos?

Comment: Dentro de un bloque `try-catch`, solo puede haber un `catch` para `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. Dentro de éste, puedes hacer un `e.getMessage()` para ver si en el valor te da información de qué FK está fallando.

Comment: Me di cuenta q no explique el detalle de mi duda, es que uso 3 tablas.
Clientes.. Localidades y Provincias..
y el id de loc y pcias es clave foranea en cliente.. entonces si yo ingreso un cliente y quiero ponerle una prov o localidad q no cargue previamente me tira esa excepcion de mysql x eso mi duda de como usar esa excepcion y mostrar una ayuda con las localidades y otra con las provincias dependiendo q campo es el incorrecto

Comment: No, eso se entiende. Pero, sea cual sea el foreign key que falla, la excepción es siempre la misma y sale de la ejecución de la misma instrucción, `pps.executeUpdate();`. Así que, o bien alguno de los campos de la excepción tiene la información (proviniente del driver JDBC) o no hay manera de diferenciarlo. Otra opción es, en caso de error, comprobar los valores a ver si están en las tablas. O, mejor aún, hacer que por aplicación el usuario solo pueda seleccionar localidades y provincias que estén en tu tabla; al fin y al cabo serán listas bastante estáticas.

Comment: Y por cierto, si te refieres al mismo concepto, normalmente una localidad está en una provincia, por lo que al indicar localidad ya estás indicando la provincia (cliente tiene una foreign key a localidad que tiene una foreign key a provincia)

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces una comprobación de si esa localidad o provincia existen? Puedes crear un método llamado, por ejemplo, `localidadExiste(String localidad)`, que te devuelva un boolean, si es true entonces pasas al INSERT y ya dentro de este INSERT puedes jugar con el catch para ver si falla en la provincia, y si es false, pues entonces devuelves el fallo de que la localidad no existe; o si lo deseas puedes hacer la comprobación de si localidad y provincia existen en tu base de datos, y asi pasas de jugar con el catch.

Comment: Y un consejo, evita tener manejar la lógica de la vista (todo lo de JOptionPane) en la clase que haces la lógica de base de datos, y meterlo separado en otra clase que llame a la de la base de datos y en función de lo que devuelva, ya manejas lo que se devolverá a la vista. Esto es principalmente por organización del código y que sepas donde se encuentra correctamente cada cosa.